# Printing content of variables using graphics method

Tags: c#, graphics

I've made a print button in my program and my intensions are to print different rows and columns with text, images and the content of variables.

I've looked into the Graphics method and made a test shown in the code below. I got some variables defined in another method and I want to print the content of those variables next to the string. Can anyone guide how to that using the graphics method?

```
private void btn_print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 827, 1169);
            pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
            pd.Print();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while printing", ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {            
        String drawString = "Test";
        e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, new Font("Verdana", 14), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), 20,20);
    }
```

Here is the code for the button defining the variables:

```
private void btn_calculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int aa = Int32.Parse(tb_windvelocity.Text);
        int bb = Int32.Parse(tb_height.Text);
        int cc = Int32.Parse(tb_area.Text);
        int dd = Int32.Parse(tb_sc.Text);
        double ee = Math.Sin((Int32.Parse(tb_angle.Text)) * (Math.PI / 180));

        double g = 0;
        if (this.cb_gust.SelectedItem==cb_gust1)
        {
            g = 3;
        }
        else if(this.cb_gust.SelectedItem == cb_gust2)
        {
           g = 15;
        }


        double ff = 5.73 * (Math.Pow(10,-2)) * (Math.Sqrt(1 + (0.15 * aa)));

        double gg = aa * (1 + (ff * (Math.Log(bb / 10))));

        double hh = 0.06 * (1 + (0.043 * aa)) * Math.Pow((bb / 10), (-0.22));

        double ii = gg * (1 - (0.41 * hh * Math.Log(g / 3600)));

        double jj1 = (0.5 * 1.225 * dd * cc * Math.Pow(ii, 2) * ee)/1000;
        double jj2 = (0.5 * 1.225 * dd * Math.Pow(ii, 2) * ee) / 1000;
        lbl_windaction1.Content = Math.Round(jj1,2);
        lbl_windaction2.Content = Math.Round(jj2,2);

    }
```

Comment: You __can't really access local variables__ from any other method, no matter for what purpose. So the simplest solution is to move them to __class level__, maybe into a class and its members, maybe into a `DataTable` or if you want to see them into a `DataGridView`or simply one or more `List<T>` etc... -  what type of storage is best is really depending on just what the content and its source is..

Comment: Okay, so lets say I move them to class level. Is it possible to use the Graphics method to print the value from them? I'm using doubles. @TaW

Comment: Yes, of course. The DrawString metod can access them just like your `string drawString`. You add a nice formt string!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private string getMyString()
{
    return "Hello world";
}

private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{            
    String drawString = this.getMyString();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, new Font("Verdana", 14), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), 20,20);
}
```

As TaW says, you can't access local variables of another method, so you sould define a method that return your variable(s) and call it inside `pd_PrintPage`.

**EDIT (updated code)**

Your code seems to be only mathematical scoped, but also *calculate* and *print* will be fired separately from two distinct buttons.

So, the principle provided by TaW is right in that case:

```
private double jj1, jj2;

private void btn_calculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double jj1 = // code removed for clarity 
    double jj2 = // code removed for clarity 

    this.jj1 = jj1;
    this.jj2 = jj2;
}
```

Then, into `pd_PrintPage` method:

```
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{            
    String drawString = this.jj1.ToString();
    String drawString2 = this.jj2.ToString();

    // now draw with graphics
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is one option but for a dozen numbers like sums etc I don't think one method per number is a good design. A class or even structure `printData` would be better.. But without knowing more we can't advise fully.

Comment: Yes, i agree, but my answer point out how to access an object defined as local in another method without save it to class level. The OP example code shows that he need a String, so my example expose a String method.

Comment: In my case I have two variables, jj1 and jj2 and they are both doubles. I have defined them in a calculation button method and this is where a calculation is done. The result is given in a label. I want to print the content if both jj1 and jj2. Should I make a new method where the calculation is done, and call for the method in both the calculation button and the print button? Maybe this is a better design?

Comment: There are many ways to skin the proverbial cat. I guess in your case it simply doesn't matter. But if the calculation is expensive, like calculating the number from a million records you read from disk or db, it is advisable to store the result to reuse when needed. It is also quite common to collect the data to __print__ from those you already have on __screen__; in this case you could make the `Labels public` (go to the designer pane and set the `Modifiers` property to  `public`!) and simply pull the readily formatted string from your `label.Text` into your `printPage` routine....

Comment: Wow, I didnt know it was possible to make the labels public! Thanks a lot @TaW

Comment: @TaW i still agree with your concept, but we don't need to store values if the calculation is simple and fast. Otherwise yes, we should keep our hard-resource-calculation in a class variable, or similar. Thomas, can you provide a full code example of you calculations? If I don't know how your code acts, i can't provide a concise answer

Comment: @T-moty, I've updated the post now and it includes both the button methods. If you look at 'jj1' and 'jj2', I want to print the results in those two variables in the pd_PrintPage method.

Comment: This worked as I wanted, thanks a lot for your help @T-moty!

Comment: Your original code still has its merits; you may want to add the option of setting two or more return values via `out`  parameters.  The same function can be called from the calculate button and  in the print routine. Here is one more thing that __sometime__ should be considered: There are cases when one would avoid dong the calculation just for the print routine, namely  when it is important to keep the display and the printout guaranteed to be in synch..

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm just a beginner and just started with programming at this scale, so I'm still in the first learning process. I'll check out the `out` parameter @TaW

Comment: @ThomasEikjeGjerde good luck with learning, and happy coding! ;)